# Is it normal that my supervisor told me to submit my thesis without any correction from him(he took only one day to look to the thesis)?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, thesis, editors, all-but-dissertation

I send my Ph.D. thesis to my supervisor, he replied on me after only one day(my thesis is 130 pages)told me that your thesis is OK and you can submit.He did not do any correction or comments!! does this happen?is it normal? I'm so happy, but also I am surprising
Good thing to mention here that my thesis is edited by a native speaker person before I send.But still, I can't believe what happened?even my thesis is not editted to a be ready for print out

Comment: This does sound like it should be a cause for concern, but some context would help. Is this a first draft? Does this thesis contain work that's already been peer reviewed? Do you have another supervisor who's also read it? Are you rushing to a deadline? I could go on...

Comment: Im rushing in deadline but i did not put pressure on my supervisor.I told him its better if you can finish it before xx date.Part of this thesis was published  in a paper.One of my supervisor(not on the same field) have quick look to it and edited some issues in case of grammers but not scientifically

Comment: But in this case: its impossible that the supervisor tell its OK you can submit without read it?if something wrong then he will not tell that?

Comment: How do you know he didn't read it? There may be reasons why your supervisor would tell you to submit without suggesting alterations, but it would depend on your situation, and you describe very little about your situation

Comment: Sometimes supervisors (advisors) for thesis will want to nit-pick and make a million changes, then more changes, and then more.  You found the other end of the scale.  Maybe I'm just old and jaded, but if it were me, as long as they gave me that PhD paper, I'd be happy.

Comment: I did not say that he did not read it.Just I'm surprising!!

Comment: Only i was in hurry,the deadline which is coming after 5 days and he only took one day to say its OK about my thesis.But i did not say to him you should finish it...i said only if you can finish it before 5 days pass

Comment: It may defend greatly on institutional norms. My advisor did not nitpick the draft, mainly leaving it to the committee to insist on some minor changes. But, it was in good shape well before the defense, and based on published work.